# In the US, why did anti-authoritarian sentiment grow only in the 1960s?

Tags: united-states

In other words, why didn't anti-authoritarian sentiment grow after other controversies like the Civil War, or World War 1? Why so much later?

> For decades, the rate of violent and property crimes in the United States had been steady and relatively
> low. But levels began to rise in the mid-1950s. By 1960, the crime rate was 50 percent higher than it had
> been in 1950; by 1970, the rate had *quadrupled*.
>       Why?
>       It was hard to say. So many changes were simultaneously rippling through American society in the 1960s—a
> population explosion, **a growing anti-authoritarian sentiment**, the expansion of civil rights, a wholesale shift
> in popular culture—that it wasn’t easy to isolate the factors driving crime.

Dubner, Levitt. *SuperFreakonomics: Global Cooling, Patriotic Prostitutes, and Why Suicide Bombers Should Buy Life Insurance* (2009). p 100.

Comment: Why do you think anti-authoritarian sentiment only showed up in the 1960s?  The women's suffrage movement was anti-authoritarian, as was the response of the general public to Prohibition.  FTM, you could even consider the rise of the KKK after the Civil War as an anti-authoritarian movement.  Another factor is that prior to WWII, those who didn't like conditions where they lived could just move out west.

Comment: @jamesqf - The KKK was more of an anti-anti-authoritarian organization. They wanted society to be much more authoritarian than the law allowed for.

Comment: I think I have that book, and I'm pretty sure they have an answer if you just read a little further.

Comment: @T.E.D.: That's a matter of one's viewpoint.  From theirs, they objected to what authority - the federal government - was telling them to do.  Many "anti-authoritarian" groups are like that: they don't really object to authority per se, they just want to be the ones with the authority.  Consider for instance how women's suffrage led to Prohibition, or the '60s left's fascination with (inherently authoritarian) socialism.

Comment: How do you define "anti-authoritarian"?  We had draft riots in the civil war, protests for women's suffrage and prohibition around the turn of the century, one president assassinated by an "anarchist", bonus marches on Washington, etc.  I believe the quote you reference is only referring to the post-war period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps to put the events in the context of the time in which they happened. Judging past events by current cultural norms paints a very false picture.

There have been anti-authoritarian movements in the US before the 1960's.

Given that they went against the prevailing authority, the early US labor movement beginning with the [Haymarket Affair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haymarket_affair) in 1886 were decidedly anti-authoritarian, widespread, and resulted in quite a bit of violent confrontations that continued for decades, until the unions were finally recognized by federal law.

The US Civil War was an attempt by several states to throw off the authority of the federal government.

And before that, an anti-authoritarian movement began around 1776, engaging in considerable violation of existing laws, that actually did prevail over the resident British authority.

Arguably, the document that emerged from that movement, the US Constitution, is somewhat anti-authoritarian in nature, especially when viewed in the context of other such documents in western nations of that time. A good deal of the Constitution limits federal powers, which was at that time a fairly new concept.

Comment: Good answer; other examples include, Thomas Jefferson and the Democratic-Republicans were a pretty strong anti-authoritarian movement.  The US Constitution was an authoritarian answer to an anti-authoritarian movement.